# AWK - enclose found strings with symbols in one command

Tags: string, awk

I have a large body of text and I print only lines that contain one of several strings. Each line can contain more than one string.

Example of the rule:

(house|mall|building)

I want to mark the found string for making the result easier to read.

Example of the result I want:

New record: Two New York houses under contract for nearly $5 million each.

New record: Two New York @house@s under contract for nearly $5 million each.

I know I can find the location, trim, add marker, add string etc.

I am asking if there is a way to mark the found string in one command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html

> **gsub**(*ere*, *repl*[, in])
>
> Behave like sub (see below), except that it shall replace all occurrences of the regular expression ...
>
> **sub**(*ere*, *repl*[, *in*  ])
>
> Substitute the string repl in place of the first instance of the
>   extended regular expression ERE in string in and return the number of
>   substitutions. An ampersand ( '&' ) appearing in the string repl shall
>   be replaced by the string from in that matches the ERE ...

```
BEGIN {
    r = "house|mall|building"
    s = "Two New York houses under contract for nearly $5 million each."
    gsub(r, "@&@", s)
    print s
}
```